# Pipe to grep not working in zsh

Tags: macos, zsh

I am doing something I always do in Bash:

```
set | grep -i path
```

and the output is

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

What's wrong? `grep --help` works, and `set | more` works too.

Answer (score 12):

Do this:

```
set > /tmp/zshset
```

Then open `/tmp/zshset` in your favorite editor. Look for `IFS`.

The default value for this, per the `zshparam` man page, is default space, tab, newline and             NUL. This last one is causing the trouble. `grep` sees the NUL (ascii 0, displayed often as `^@`) and thinks that this is a binary file.

Possible solutions:

- Set IFS to some other value. This might cause problems if something else you do expects that NUL is a valid delimiter.
- Use `grep -a` as suggested by KeithB (or its equivalent `--binary-files=text`)
- Create a new alias for yourself which uses `grep -a` to save yourself a little bit of typing
- Adapt to looking at your PATH through other means (e.g. `env | grep -i path`, `echo $PATH`) -- I think the other solutions are simpler

Comment: Clear and complete explanation. Thanks - I learned something today.

Comment: I'll second that +1. Using the alternatives you suggest makes me know more, so I'll use those for now. I don't want to mess with unrelated variables just to get a command to work.

Comment: BTW, yes, the IFS value is not looking healthy in TextMate. I'll leave it alone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is going on, but you can pass the `-a` flag to grep to force it to treat its input as text, regardless of what it thinks that it is.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried with `grep --binary-files=text` which works, but I wonder why this doesn't work off the bat.... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround if your `grep` doesn't implement `-a` is to do:

```
$ set | cat -v | grep foo
```